# How to test component that contains a component connected to Redux in Enzyme / React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

There's a familiar gotcha when testing **React** **components** that are connected to **Redux** in **Enzyme**. You may have run into this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(YourComponent)
```

This is **resolved** by exporting the component under test twice:

```
export class YourComponent extends Component {}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

And in your test **import YourComponent as an object**:

```
import { YourComponent } from '../pathToYourComponent'
```

I've run into a novel scenario regarding this issue.
I'm testing a connected component, and I'm using the solution above to resolve that issue, however inside that component there is another connected component that gets rendered when certain props are present.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    const { arrayOfObjects } = this.props;

    let nestedConnectedComponent; 
    if (arrayOfObjects.length) {
      nestedConnectedComponent = arrayOfObjects.map((ele, idx) => (
        <NestedConnectedComponent
          key={idx}
        />
      ))
    }
    return (
      <div> {arrayOfObjects} </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(){}
function mapDispatchToProps(){}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent);
```

How do you avoid the "could not find store" error when you are testing a component that contains a component that is connected to redux?

The component is being **shallow** rendered in the latest version of Enzyme.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get this error if you use shallow rendering, from docs

'Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.'

Comment: This is incorrect. It's not that behavior is being asserted on ChildComponents, it's that the ChildComponent is connected to redux, and regardless I'm only using shallow in the test. Discussion here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/183

Comment: why? I am using shallow rending to unit test my components as mentioned by docs and children are not rendered thus there is no error "could not find store"

Comment: That is not the behavoir of shallow rendeing, take a look to reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html. If you shallow render a component its childs won't be rendered nor instantiated. Could you paste your test code to check?

Comment: Testing connected components isn't the problem. It's testing components that have children that are connected (or are otherwise decorated). This is not an issue the docs cover.

Comment: The issue you mentioned is closed, maybe you are using an old version of enzyme. I am using enzyme 3.6 and I never faced this issue.

Comment: I'm on the latest version of enzyme. Did you check out the discussion?

Comment: I just wrote a test for a component with a connected component as a child (from redux react training). You can see that the test just go fine with shallow rending and there is not need to provide a store. https://codesandbox.io/s/2pqwq12j9y (see tests, test file is /src/
Dummy.test.js)

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: @dijkstraman check out all the comments by link you have provided. there are several cases people run into when even using `.shallow` full render was executed(I can recall calling `.html()` on wrapper and some related issue in _chai-enzyme_, maybe I miss something else)

Comment: Could you take look to the test I wrote https://codesandbox.io/s/2pqwq12j9y , there is no issue when shallow rendering a component with a connected component as a child. Test run with jest enzyme

Comment: @zero_cool, could you review your comments for this answer? This does work for me :)